# Under what conditions will writes to non-volatile variables be unseen by other threads? Can I force such conditions for experimental purposes?

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile, non-volatile

I've recently been reading a lot here on SO and elsewhere about threaded memory management, in particular, the use of the `volatile` keyword.  I'm beginning to feel reasonably confident with the concept, however, in order to full appreciate the effect it has I would like to try and run some experiments which illustrate it.

Here is my setup: I have a producer thread (it reads audio data from the microphone, related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375958/2d-volatile-arrays-will-self-assignment-help-or-do-i-need-atomicintegerarray), but the actual data doesn't matter) which passes on data as `byte[]` to a separate consumer thread.  The way in which the data is shared between threads is the primary variable in my experiment: I have tried an `ArrayBlockingQueue`; I have tried a shared `volatile byte[]` reference (with a `array = array` self-reference as recommended in [this blog post](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.co.uk/2009/06/volatile-arrays-in-java.html)); and I have also tried a normal non-volatile `byte[]` with no self reference.  Both threads also write the data to disk as they go along.

My hope was to find that, after running for some length of time, the non-volatile `byte[]` version would have discrepancies between the data that the producer attempted to share and the data that the consumer read data due to some memory writes not being visible in time, while the other two versions would have exactly the same data logged by each thread because of the precautions taken to ensure publication of memory writes.  As it happens however, I find 100% accuracy whatever method I use.

I can already think of a few possibilities as to why this occurred, but my main question is:  **under what conditions are writes to a non-volatile variable unseen to another thread**, which as far as I understand is the whole point of `volatile`?  And **can I force these conditions for experimental purposes**?

My thoughts so far are:

- Maybe the two threads are running on the same core and share the same cache, so memory writes are visible immediately?
- Maybe CPU load is a factor?  Perhaps I need many threads all doing different things before I see any problem?
- Maybe I need to wait longer: perhaps such problems are very rare?

Could anyone either suggest how I could design such an experiment or explain why my idea is flawed?

Many thanks.

Comment: It's more that under many conditions the non-volatiles are not guaranteed to be in sync, than that in any certain conditions they'de be guaranteed to be out of sync. The most likely way to trigger it is in a tight loop, but that is not *guaranteed* to happen.

Comment: Yeah, I understand it isn't guaranteed, and that makes this very problematic - so perhaps it just isn't feasible to run an experiment like this.  Nonetheless I wanted to see if anyone had any ideas, so thanks for your comment.

Comment: on intel CPUs writes are ordered, that's why it's hard to observe any inconsistency. compiler/runtime may reorder the instructions for optimization; if we have enough insight in how it works we may create a situation that reorder happens.

Comment: x86 and x64 CPUs use MESI to keep caches coherent, so I'm afraid you will never observe stale values. The main point of `volatile` on single processor machines is to prevent instruction reordering. If you carefully think about it, you might drive the compiler into reordering something, so that you can observe writes that happen in a order different from the one you wrote.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu The best bet is to help the JIT to hoist a variable - see my example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to easily observe the effects of a lack of barriers in your code on an x86 because it has a fairly strong memory model. But that does not mean that the same code would not break on a different architecture. On x86, you generally need to play with the JIT compiler and help it make an optimisation that would not be allowed with a volatile variable, for example variable hoisting.

The code below, on my machine with hotspot 7u25 server, never ends if the variable is non-volatile but stops promptly if it is. You might need to change the sleep delay depending on your machine.

```
public class Test {

    static /* volatile */ boolean done = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Runnable waiter = new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                while(!done);
                System.out.println("Exited loop");
            }
        };
        new Thread(waiter).start();
        Thread.sleep(100); //wait for JIT compilation
        done = true;
        System.out.println("done is true");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very clever idea, works for me too.  I think this is a great illustration, thanks!

Comment: @gstackoverflow not sure why you want to remove the Override annotation - it is good practice to use it where applicable.

Comment: @assylias I tryed to compile this code and I see compilation error.

Comment: I am sorry. maybe it is bug of my IDE

Comment: @gstackoverflow what source language level is your compiler set to? Implementing an interface method is a valid use of `@Override` on java 6 or later but is not allowed by java 5 (only true overrides of a superclass method can take the annotation in 5).

Comment: @Ian Roberts Yeah.you are right. only in 5-th version it is not possible - possible for 6+ versions